# Объединение значений из БД

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть две таблицы, со списками всех новостей (название новости, контент новости) и таблица с комментариями к новости. На главной странице нужно вывести название, контент и количество комментариев к новости. Название и контент вывел, т.к. данных находятся в одной таблице (выводятся в цикле for), а с выводом кол-ва комментариев возникли проблемы, незнаю как вывести. Получается, что нужно выводить кол-во комментариев соответствующих данной статье. Как так сделать подскажите?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно в одном запросе получить и все поля из таблицы новостей, и кол-во комментариев. Что-то типа:

```
SELECT news.*, COUNT(comments.*) AS count_comments
FROM news
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.id_news = news.id_news
GROUP BY 1
```